# How to insert a Structure into a node of a LinkedList using C?

Tags: c, insert, structure

so I'm trying to enter the information of a Student, including first name, last name, score, and zip code, into a single node. I would then be able to insert the info of another student into the next node, and so on, and be able to access them.

The part I'm having issues with is adding lastname, score, and zip code into the node. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it. It's probably something really simple, but I simply don't know how.

You can see the problem arise in the insert function. I'm able to insert the first name, but not the last name. Something may be wrong with my fundamentals, but if they are, just let me know.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* inserting nodes at the END of a linked list */

void Insert(char *f, char *l, float s, char *z);
void Print();

struct node
{
    struct Student *now;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head; /* it will be created in the GLOBAL region of the memory */
struct node *tail = NULL;

struct Student {
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    float score;
    char zip[20];
};


int main()
{
    //int i,n,x;
    //int x;
    head = NULL;

    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    float score;
    char zip[20];



    printf("\nPlease input records of students: ");

    printf("\nFirst name: ");
    scanf("%s", first);

    printf("\nLast name: ");
    scanf("%s", last);

    printf("\nScore: ");
    scanf("%f", &score);

    printf("\nZip code: ");
    scanf("%s", zip);

    printf("\n------ This is the Print records function so far: \n\n");
    Insert(first, last, score, zip);

    Print();

    return 0;
}

void Insert(char *f, char *l, float s, char *z)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->now=f;

    // Problem: how do I insert the other variables (last, score, zip) into a student structure and into node?
    //temp->now.lastname =l; //Doesn't work
    temp->next=NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        tail=temp;
        return;
    }
    tail->next=temp;
    tail=temp;
}

void Delete(int n)
{
    struct node* temp1 = head;
    int i;

    if (n==1)
    {

        head = temp1->next; /*head now points to the second node */

        free(temp1);

        return;

    }

    for(i=0; i<n-2; i++)
        temp1=temp1->next; /* temp1 points to (n-1)th node */
    struct node* temp2 = temp1->next; /* nth node */
    temp1->next = temp2->next; /*(n+1)th node */
    free(temp2); /* delete temp2 */
}

void Print()
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = head;

    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ",temp->now);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `now` is a pointer to `struct Student`, `f` is a pointer to character(s). One of these things is not like the other...

Answer (score 0):

You assignd `temp->now` to incompatible pointer `f`, I guess the compiler has complained for that.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the linked list Node you have another pointer to the STRUCT so first you need to allocate memory for that also.

`temp->now = (struct Student *) malloc(sizeof(struct Student));`

Now you can access the individual fields and the update them accordingly. 
`strncpy(temp->now.firstname, f, sizeof(temp->now.firstname));`

```
strncpy(temp->now.lastname, f, sizeof(temp->now.lastname));
temp->now.score = s;
```